# How to typesafe expression for @Input() in angular 2+?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to define a function for a the `@Input()` in an Angular component?

For example to define a method which returns a boolean value:

`@Input callback:` `//(allow just methods with boolean return value)`

`@Input callback: Function` `// this is not what i prefere since it accepts all type of functions.`

Comment: `()=> true` is a signature for a function that doesn't accept a parameter but returns a boolean value.

Comment: Do you also care about the function arguments? E.g. is it required the argument to be only one or of a specific type?

Comment: thank you guys! this worked for me. i was confused about the pattern, since the way of define a callback method in an interface is slightely different.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `type`.

```js
export type MyInput = () => boolean;

@Input() callback: MyInput;
```

Here you can read more about [Function type expressions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions)